# Initialize a ViewDataDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to build a function that takes a parameter and passes it to the `System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary` constructor. This is my code:

```
// this WORKS, but need to pass as parameter
var dic1 = new System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary { { "key", "value" } };

// this DOES NOT WORK
Test({ "key", "value" }); // I try do not have 'new Something({"", ""})'

function Test(object myParam) {
    var dic2 = new System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary { myParam };
    //...
}
```

Is there a way to pass the parameter like I did, without need to pass the entire
`new System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary { { "key", "value" } }` as parameter to the `Test` function?

**PS.** This is some test code explaining the problem

```
// WORKS
var dic1 = new System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary { { "key", "value" } };

// DOES NOT WORK

// A CASE
string[] myArr = { "key", "value" }; // OK
var dic2 = new System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary { myArr }; // NOK

// B CASE    
KeyValuePair<string, object> myPair = {"key", "value"}; // NOK
var dic3 = new System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary { myPair }; // OK
```

**PPS**. multiple arguments case:

```
// WORKS
var dic1 = new ViewDataDictionary { { "key", "value" }, {"key2", "value2"} };
var dic2 = new ViewDataDictionary { (replace w/ one single obj/arr impossible?)};
```

Comment: Why don't you create the Dictionary first and then simply add your entries as you need them? BTW: you could also consider adding the relevant data to your model instead of passing it via ViewData.

Comment: Usualy I have a single key-value, so create a dictionary for that... I just want to pass `{"key", "value"}` if possible

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk, thanks, see my PS ;)

Comment: @Serge could you please let me know whether the answer I've provided solves the problem or there are other issues? I've extended it with the additional examples. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to achieve what you want because curly brackets can be used only for the [collection initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx). The parser treats these curly brackets in a special way only if they are connected to the `new` keyword. It parses them and generates a bunch of the `Add` calls.

If you want to pass only key and value it can be done like this:

```
Test("key", "value"); 

void Test(string key, object value) {
    var dic2 = new ViewDataDictionary { { key, value  } };
    //...
}
```

The `ViewDataDictionary` contains a constructor which accepts another `ViewDataDictionary`:

```
Test(new ViewDataDictionary { { key, value  } }); 

void Test(ViewDataDictionary dictionary) {
     var dic2 = new ViewDataDictionary(dictionary);
     //...
}
```

If you need to add some values from one `ViewDataDictionary` to another existing `ViewDataDictionary` you could use the following code:

```
Test(new ViewDataDictionary { { key, value  } }); 

void Test(ViewDataDictionary dictionary) {
     var dic2 = new ViewDataDictionary();
     // ... initialize dic2
     foreach (var pair in dictionary)
     {
            dic2.Add(pair);
     }
}
```

If there is a need to pass an array (of `KeyValuePair` elements) to initialize the dictionary it can be done in this way:

```
Test(new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, object>("key1", "value1"),
             new KeyValuePair<string, object>("key2", "value2") }); 

void Test(KeyValuePair<string, object>[] pairs) {
     var dic2 = new ViewDataDictionary();
     foreach (var pair in pairs)
     {
            dic2.Add(pair);
     }
     //...
}
```

Comment: probably I miss something, but why do you say "add an item"? I don't use any `.Add()` call....

Comment: I've changed the description. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: so, if I would like to add 2 pairs, I need 4 arguments... etc?

Comment: There are many ways to do it. You could have 4 arguments if you always need to add only to elements into the dictionary. You could also pass an array of the `KeyValuePair` instances.

Comment: I am afraid that an Array of keyvaluespair will not work... How it casts by the way `KeyValuePair<string, object> myPair = {"key", "value"};` (this does not compile)?

Comment: as is, is shorter to use a `new ViewDataDictionary { { "key", "value" }, {"key2", "value2"} }` as argument, what I initially tried to avoid :) Thanks anyway